# Override CSS selector for some elements

Tags: html, css

I have a html-page which I would like to style (using IE9).

The following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #komponenter select,
    #komponenter input
    {
         width: 180px;
         box-sizing:content-box; 
    }

    .special_box { width: 50px; height: 150px; }
</style>

... snipp ...

<div id="col2" class="kolumn">

    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Verksamhetskod)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Verksamhetskod)
    <br />

    @Html.Label("Lat/Long")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LatitudTecken)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Latitud)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LongitudTecken)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Longitud)
    <br />

    @Html.Label("3 Överväganden:")
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Overvagande)
    <br />

    @Html.Label("1 Ingångsvärden:")
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Ingangsvarde, new { @class = "special_box" })
    <br />
</div>
```

The html renders fine, the problem is that the .special_box width gets overridden by the css-statements above (the height works fine). I've tried putting the class first in the style section, but it did'nt make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a matter of specificity: try this instead (assuming `.special_box` is an `input` element)

```
#komponenter select,
#komponenter input
{
     width: 180px;
     box-sizing:content-box; 
}

#komponenter input.special_box {
     width: 50px; height: 150px; 
}
```

a rule like `#komponenter input` has a specificity of `101` (1 id, 0 classes, 1 element)
while `.special_box` has a specificity of `10` (1 class, 0 elements)

see http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ for more info

Comment: Here's another good article on CSS specificity: [Specifics on CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

the css above have a higher [specificity](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) (1-0-1) than your `.specialbox` (0-1-0). to raise it, you have to "be more specific":

```
/*here we add a few more selectors to .special_box to be more specific*/
#komponenter input.special_box (1-1-1)
//   1-0-0 for #komponenter
//   0-0-1 for input
// + 0-1-0 for .special_box
// = 1-1-1
```

or just override the styles you want to take effect with `!important`

```
#komponenter input.special_box{
    width: 50px !important;   /*override width*/
    height: 150px;
}
```